# Unable to hide a column on CellClickEvent in C# datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView as shown in this link "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgwaD.png".

OnCLick of Image in flags column I want to add a new row below the clicked row with only 2 columns which are "Start", "End", "Status" and "Flags" will be hidden for the newly added row.

DataGrid population is done as below:

```
CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();
chkbox.Text = "click";
//column 0
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkcol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkcol.HeaderText = "Select";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkcol);                          // Want to hide on ImageClick event

//column 1
DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imageCol.HeaderText = "Package";
imageCol.Image = plus_img;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageCol);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

//column 2
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col2.HeaderText = "Latest Update";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col2);

//column 3
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col3.HeaderText = "Installed Version";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col3);

//column 4
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col4.HeaderText = "Details";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col4);
```

Using CellContentClick:

```
 int col = e.ColumnIndex; // clicked column index
 int row = e.RowIndex;    // clicked row index

  dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

I am using last line to hide column 0 for next row. But it is giving me following error

"Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Visible' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only". When I checked Read Only property for the grid and the column it is set to "false". Please help me with this.

Comment: How do you add Rows below the clicked row? Can you simply set Flags property to empty string when you are adding the new Row?

Comment: I am not able to add row below the clicked one it is getting added at the last position and I don't know about the Flags property.

Comment: Can you show us some code to illustrate how dataGridView1 is populated?

Comment: Is this a sample code? I can't see "Start", "End", "Status" and "Flags".

Comment: This is the original code. Grid in the hyperlink was sample one. I am in need to hide "Select" column onClick event.

Answer (score 2):

To hidden a columns why don't you set `Visible` property of column directly?

```
dataGridView1.Columns[col].Visible = false
```

> I am using last line to hide column 0 for next row.

Look like you expect hidden a cell and your code will not work. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx) the `Visible` property of `DataGridViewCell` are read only.

BTW, to hidden a cell you can work around by change `Style` of cell. Set Forecolor and background color has the same color and set `ReadOnly = true` to prevent editing.

Hope this help.

Comment: This question is about Winforms not Asp.net